# What does this MACRO function do?

Tags: c

This fucntion:

```
FIFO_ELEM_AT(p_fifo, index) ((uint8_t*) ((uint8_t*) p_fifo->elem_array) + (p_fifo->elem_size) * (index))
```

and "p_fifo" was defined as:

```
typedef struct
{
    void* elem_array;
    uint32_t elem_size;
    uint32_t array_len;
    uint32_t head;
    uint32_t tail;
    fifo_memcpy memcpy_fptr; /* must be a valid function or NULL */
  } fifo_t;
```

Overall it's trying to do something to a static fifo data structure. I can't really tell what you can possibly achieve by the calculation described in the function. Please help!

Comment: Did you try breaking it apart into individual lines and printing/debugging the values?

Comment: Look up "queue" data structure

Comment: you can ignore the outer `(uint8_t *)` , it is redundant.  If you still don't understand then ask more specifically which bit you are stuck on.

Comment: What does "index" and "elem_array" do respectively, in this scenario? Why does "elem_array" have to be a pointer, what's its purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentation for the code you are looking at.
Otherwise you are stuck with guessing. You seem to ask for help with guessing.
Here are my guesses:

- The mentioned struct type describes all the information for handling an instance of a special data construct.
- Because of the name, it is probably a FIFO aka "ringbuffer", aka "queue" (as commented by M.M.)
- It needs an accompanying memory, to be used as the actual FIFO.
- The memory to use is referenced by a pointer to it, "elem_array".
- "elem_size" is the size of one element in the FIFO
- "head" references the next element to be returned from FIFO
- "tail" references the last element added to the FIFO
- or the other way around
- "memcpy_fptr" references a potentially optimized function to move elements to and from the FIFO
- the quoted macro provides access to the element in the FIFO at a given index
- in the form of a pointer to uint8_t; instead of a pointer-to-type-of-element
- the macro gets the address to the FIFO, does some pointer arithmetic (including the size of elements and the given index) and thereby evaluates to the result: uint8_t-pointer to indexed element

On top of my guesses, here are my opinion-based recommendations:

- when using the result (pointer to uint8_t), cast it to appropriate type
- when using the macro, make sure that you give an index to an existing element,  at least an element which has been added, with a meaningful value
- when using the macro, give an index to an element which has not been returned from the FIFO yet
- do not use the macro, it seems to go against the idea of a FIFO,
  with the possible exception to get info on the content of the FIFO for debugging purposes